# Does Laravel cursor lock the table?

Tags: database, laravel, model, cursor

I have some features that working with large amount data. I'm trying to use the Laravel model cursor to get data from database.
My concern is whether the Laravel model cursor will lock the table, because the feature will work with large amount data, so it will take time to execute. If the table is locked, another features need to wait until the feature finished.

Does Laravel cursor lock the table?

Comment: When you say laravel cursor, you mean the `cursor()`method? That's just a php generator at the end of the day.

Comment: Hi @IGP Yes, I did. For example: User::cursor(). I'm not sure it will lock the table or not.

Comment: I don't think so. It calls \PDOStatement::execute() once and that's it. [Relevant code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L357)